# How to prompt users to install app from supported source?

Tags: security

Sometimes, users find and install our app from unsupported sources. These alternative sources may have been tampered with. How should users be prompted to download the official app from the app store/play store?

Comment: In what context do you want to encourage this?  Do you mean that after they already installed the app from an unsupported source, you want to ask them to reinstall it?

Comment: Exactly. They already have it but they didn't get it from the app store.

Comment: Do you have the capability to detect it is from an unsupported source or is this a blanket statement to all of the users?

Comment: We have the capability to detect. Only users who have the unsupported version would receive a message.

Comment: Highlight the benefits of using the supported app store. Centralised / automated updates, more secure, easier to manage subscriptions / payments, easier to remove the app later...

Answer (score 2):

Send the user a push notification informing them that their app is not up to date ( not that the version they have might be tampered with) and offer them an update from the app store to ensure they have the real app.

The wording of it is the most important part.

Comment: Hey David, do you know any examples of apps that do this?

Comment: Hi Ben, not off the top of my head, I would say if there is an app that does this, they dont advertise that you might have a corrupt version of their app. Lots of apps though ask for permission to update.